# Exchange powershell Export-csv

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

First off just a little warning that my PowerShell skills are very limited, so I may be re-inventing the wheel and doing it badly.

Anyway to the point I’m trying to create/run a script to pull all records of delivered mail to all accounts using the message tracking log. The issue I’m having is when exporting my results to csv it almost seems as if the results are encrypted. Below is the code I’ve managed to piece together:

```
$msg = Get-TransportServer server_to_query | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start "10/01/2014 10:00:00" -End "10/01/2014 11:00:00" -EventID deliver | select-object -ExpandProperty Recipients | Group-Object | sort count -desc | ft -auto
```

Now I know it gives me the information I want as when I do the below it displays the first 10 records as well as how many in total.

```
$msg.count
$msg | select -first 10
```

However when i do the below its not exporting it to anything at even looks close.

```
$msg | Export-CSV export.csv
```

Its most likely to be really basic what im missing or not understanding however I feel like I'm going round in cycles now. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: How does "almost encrypted" look like?

Comment: Do not use  `ft -auto` if you intend to export the data. Format-Table would break the objects. Try removing that from your `$msg` assignment. There is more to do but that is the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that you populate `$msg` with results for `format-table`. Almost anyone would say that it is fine for shell ouput only. If you ever intend to do anything else with the data `Format-Table` is not the way to go. First, remove the `ft -auto`

```
$msg = Get-TransportServer server_to_query | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize Unlimited -Start "10/01/2014 10:00:00" -End "10/01/2014 11:00:00" -EventID deliver | select-object -ExpandProperty Recipients | Group-Object | sort count -desc
```

After that it will export better but you will see things like this in your csv:

```
"System.Collections.ArrayList","17","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]"
```

Since most of this data is just an email address repeated over and over i would wonder if you export should be something like this.

```
$msg | select name,count -first 10 | Export-Csv c:\temp\test.csv
```

Dont know if that is the output you are going for but it looks like it is.

Comment: A thousand times yes! If you ever find yourself starting a command `$variable = ` and ending that same pipe with a `Format-` command smack your hand and try again. Format commands are for exactly what they say, formatting output, not for collecting and storing data (in a variable for example).

Comment: Thank you all for your input yet another lesson learned and learned well. Matt your last bit is 100% right I did need to add in the pipe to select the data to keep the file clean of unneeded information.